pgfplots: shifted axis with set layers
When using set layers to draw several axis on the same set of layers, I get alignment problems. Here's a typical setup where several axes are aligned with respect to each other, using xshift and yshift to define offsets.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
  scale only axis,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{set layers=standard}
  \begin{axis} [
        name=square,
        width=7cm,
        height=3cm,
      ]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis} [
        name=cube,
        at=(square.south west),
        anchor=north west,
        yshift=-1cm, % <--- This seems to be the issue.
        width=3cm,
        height=3cm,
      ]
    \addplot{x^3};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis} [
        name=neg,
        width=3cm,
        height=3cm,
        at=(cube.south east),
        xshift=1cm,
      ]
    \addplot{-x^3};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


As you can see, the third axis is not aligned as intended (and I did not use any of the forbidden outer anchors). When I remove the set layers, the alignment works as expected.

Why is this happening?
Is it a bug or expected behavior?

(I know that I can work around the issue by avoiding the yshift and instead anchoring to a shifted variable, but that is not what this question is about.)

I went ahead and reported this as a bug.

Here is a simplified version of your MWE:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\begin{axis}[
name=axis,
yshift=0.5cm,
%cell picture=true,
]
\end{axis}
\draw[red] (axis.south west) rectangle (axis.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


As can be seen, the anchors are placed incorrectly.
Now with cell picture=true :

The anchors are correct. Here are the "Technical Internals" from the manual section 4.28 :

/pgfplots/cell picture=true|false|if necessary (initially true)
This
key is set automatically by pgfplots if necessary (for example by set
layers). Typically, pgfplots creates a so-called “cell picture”. A
cell picture is a separate picture which is typeset into a node.
Finally, the node is shifted to fulfill special anchor requirements.
The necessity for a cell picture is given if the anchor of an axis is
only known after the complete axis has been drawn. The initial choice
true means that pgfplots will create a cell picture for every axis.
This allows all anchors, but it is unsuited if multiple graphics
layers are desired or if one wants SVG export. In order to create a
cell picture, pgfplots interrupts the embedding tikzpicture, draws a
new tikzpicture, and finally typesets the result into a node. The
choice false tells pgfplots to draw its paths directly into the
embedding tikzpicture. Such an approach is necessary if the axis shall
use layers of the embedding tikzpicture. This is possible if and only
if the anchor can be determined without actually drawing the complete
axis. If so, pgfplots will modify the transformation matrix in
advance. Note that axes with cell picture=false will contain all the
usual anchors – the only difference is that the axis itself can only
use one of the following anchors for its alignment: north, north west,
west, south west, south, south east, east, north east, north, center,
origin, above origin, left of origin, right of origin, below origin.
The choice if necessary will check if the chosen anchor is one of the
list above. If so, it will use cell picture=false. Otherwise, it will
use cell picture=true.

The manual says cell picture=true is unsuited if layers are desired. I do not know why -it seems to solve the problem in the above example and in the original code.
Relevant comment in the code of pgfplots.code.tex line 8896:

% cell picture=false or cell picture=if necessary
%
% anchor processing is special in this case! The standard
% anchor processing uses a posteriori shifts. This feature
% here REQUIRES a priori shifts.
% Prepare special handling for these shifts:


The problem is that cell picture=true pretty much negates most of what set layers is good for. The code is a bit long for this comment, but try plotting two axis on top of each other, both with grid lines and some plotted data. With set layers, both grid lines are behind both data. With cell picture=true the grid lines of the second axis are in front of the data of the first one.

You already has your own solution to your practical problem and now with my answer here you have an explanation to why it is happening. -it is not a bug and not an error, but a technical detail that can not be remedied. What more are you looking for?

"here you have an explanation to why it is happening. -it is not a bug and not an error, but a technical detail that can not be remedied." Really? I don't see that stated anywhere in your answer or the manual (that I can find). As to the explanation: You certainly illustrate the problem in a more concise manner but I still don't understand why the anchors are wrong (nor can I see a technical reason why they should have to be). The drawing itself is shifted correctly, after all.

OK. Let us agree to disagree. When the author of PGFPlot write something like "This feature % here REQUIRES a priori shifts.", I chose to trust it. You could find someone willing to rewrite this part of PGFPlots.

Sure, we can agree to disagree. I take the comment you mention to mean that a priori shifts are necessary and thus undertaken. This introduces some limitations like only certain anchors being known in time, as explained in the manual, but that should be it. As you can see in my MWE, the cube axis is indeed shifted correctly, which is done a priori. The only thing that's not shifted correctly are the anchors that axis exposes a posteriori.

In the pgfplots'documentation section 4.19.4 Alignment In Array Form (Subplots) , you can align by putting the pictures in an array and using trim left, trim right and baseline.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
      \begin{axis} [
        width=7cm,
        height=3cm,
      ]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]
      \begin{axis} [
        width=3cm,
        height=3cm,
      ]
    \addplot{x^3};
  \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis right]
      \begin{axis} [
        width=3cm,
        height=3cm,
        % height=4cm,%<-- align base
      ]
    \addplot{-x^3};
  \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}



This does not address my question at all.
